# Exitstence of homomorphisms between fields implies existence of an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Simple Question for making sure : Let $F$, $L$ are fields such that there are homomorphisms between $F$ and $L $ (Then they become injective). Then is there an isomorphism between $F$, $L$ ?

My attempt : By the existence of the homomorphisms, $L \le F$ and $F \le L$.  So $ 1 = [L  : L]= [L:F][F:L]$. So $[L : F]$=1 and $L\cong F$.

This argument works?

Comment: Compare $F=\mathbb C$ and $L=\mathbb C(t)$.

Comment: O,K, Thanks! I'll try to check that whether the map $t \mapsto 0 $ is a homomorphism of fields $L \to F$

Comment: Let $X$ be a set of size $2^{\aleph_0}$ not containing $t$. $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic to the algebraic closure of ${\mathbb Q}(X)$ and also to the algebraic closure of the isomorphic field ${\mathbb Q}(X\cup\{t\})$. This leads to $\mathbb C\cong \overline{\mathbb Q(X)}\subseteq   \overline{\mathbb Q(X)}(t)\subseteq  \overline{\mathbb Q(X\cup\{t\})}\cong {\mathbb C}$. This shows that the outer field $\mathbb C$ is mutually embeddable with the inner field $ \overline{\mathbb Q(X)}(t)\cong {\mathbb C}(t)$. The outer field is algebraically closed, the inner is not, so they are not isomorphic.